# .datum multiple values in NVD3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using the Stacked Area Chart from NVD3.js but having an issue displaying data from multiple JSON API.

It seems my issue is within

```
d3.select('#nvd3-area svg')
  .datum(data2)
  .call(chart);
```

How can I combine `data2` with `data1` in `datum`?

Full script is here https://jsfiddle.net/zatddaat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add each serie to a `data` array:

```
  var data = [];
  data.push(data1);
  data.push(data2);
```

I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/5yp1dkfn/

Comment: Thank you very much. Especially for updating the fiddle. It does seem to be adding the two values together though. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Sorry, not to worry. It seems that is how the Stacked Area Charts are. Cheers again.

Comment: @Darren *"It seems that is how the Stacked Area Charts are."* No, it's not: right now you **don't have** a stacked area chart, you have just two areas one in front of the other.

Comment: The chart I based it upon seems to follow the same as the one in the fiddle above. http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav